# TestNG not running test on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation, testng

Any idea why TestNG is not running my test?
this is the class code(java):

```
public class main {
@Test
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException
```

this is the path on eclipse:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oIWq.png)

and this is the XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="test.main"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a `main()` method for your test code, and my guess is that trying to use one is bypassing TestNG entirely.

Comment: I'm not sure a `@Test` method can have arguments. Anyway, when your test method would run, from where would it get the value for `args`? Added: they can but maybe you are not following the rules for that, http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-methods (see 5.6).

Comment: remove String array argument from main method and try. it may works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Posted here a demo template for Your testng.You just need to take a class and declear webdriver. `@BeforeMethod` will execute before start any `@Test` then  `@AfterMethod`  Hope it will help you.

```
package stackoverflow;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.*;

    public class DemoTestNGClass {
        public static WebDriver driver;
        @BeforeMethod
        public void setUp1() throws Exception {

            driver= new ChromeDriver();


        }
        @Test
        public void Homepage() throws InterruptedException {
    //Your operation
        }

        @Test
        public void ListingPage() throws InterruptedException {

    //Your operation
        }

        @AfterMethod
        public void afterresult(){
            driver.close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether Eclipse plugin for `TestNG` is present on your machine.
2. If not install latest from Help => Eclipse Marketplace.
3. Restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue earlier.

I just changed from

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

to

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

And it worked.